# Expo eas-cli iOS build failing (expo 47)

Tags: react-native, expo

I have created an app using React Native and am trying to create an iOS app store build through Expo's eas-cli.

When running eas build --platform ios the Fastlane build failed with unknown error
i get this error
❌  (ios/Pods/boost/boost/container_hash/hash.hpp:131:33)

129 | #else
130 |         template

> 131 |         struct hash_base : std::unary_function<T, std::size_t> {};
> |                                 ^ no template named 'unary_function' in namespace 'std'; did you mean '__unary_function'?
> 132 | #endif
> 133 |
> 134 |         struct enable_hash_value { typedef std::size_t type; };

Answer (score 0):

You can set up your `eas.json` like this

```json
    {
      "cli": {
        "version": ">= 5.2.0"
      },
      "build": {
        "dev": {
          "channel": "dev",
          "android": {
            "buildType": "app-bundle",
            "autoIncrement": true
          },
          "ios": {}
        }
      }
    }
```

then you can run the following command in your terminal `eas build --platform ios --profile dev`. I hope this helps!